# Move text from right side to below depending on class

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my text move depending on the orientation of an image, but I am having trouble placing the text content where I want it.

How far I have come:

https://jsfiddle.net/sj9jgvyq/16/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".change").click(function() {
   if ( $(".content").hasClass("landscape")) {
     $(".content").removeClass("landscape");
      $(".content").addClass("portrait");
      $("img").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/200x400")
    } else {
     $(".content").addClass("landscape");
      $(".content").removeClass("portrait");
      $("img").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/400x200")
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.content.landscape .first {
  display: inline-block;
}

.content.landscape .second {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.content.landscape .third {
  display: block;
}

.content.landscape .change {
  display: block;
}

.content.portrait .first {
  display: inline-block;
}

.content.portrait .second {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.content.portrait .third {
  display: inline-block;
}

.content.portrait .change {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content landscape">
   <button class="change">
    Change
  </button>
  <div class="first">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200">
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    Text Second
  </div>
  <div class="third">
    Text Third
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is for "Third Text" to be directly below "Second Text" when in portrait and below image when in landscape.

Press button to see the change. Would prefer a solution without javascript, if possible.

Clarification: I know how to detect the orientation but I am unable to put the text content where I want it.

Answer (score 0):

To do this with purely CSS, you will want to use `@media` queries.  Have portrait be the default layout, then use a media query to change to the landscape view if the screen is wide enough.

For example (using 400px as the width at which to change the layout):

```
.content {
    .first {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .second {
       display: inline-block;
       vertical-align: top;
    }
    .third {
       display: inline-block;
    }
    .change {
       display: block;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
    .third {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

For more on media queries, you can look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: This does not help with placing Third Text below Second Text when in portrait.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question.  Are you trying to have "Second Text" always stay beside the image with just "Third Text" shifting?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the preferred solution, as it uses javascript. But it gives the desired result.

https://jsfiddle.net/sj9jgvyq/18/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".change").click(function() {
    if ( $(".content").hasClass("landscape")) {
      $(".content").removeClass("landscape");
      $(".content").addClass("portrait");
      $("img").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/200x400");
      $(".third").detach().appendTo(".side");
    } else {
      $(".content").addClass("landscape");
      $(".content").removeClass("portrait");
      $("img").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/400x200");
      $(".third").detach().appendTo(".bottom");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.content .first {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.content .side {
  display: inline-block;
}

.content .change {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content landscape">
   <button class="change">
    Change
  </button>
  <div class="first">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200">
  </div>
  <div class="side">
    <div class="second">
      Text Second
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="third">
      Text Third
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```